# Multithreading: first access from another thread after being written... do I need volatile?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hope the question is easy to understand. In any case, let's write some code...

```
struct MyClass 
{
    int a;
    std::vector<char> b;
    ...
}

MyClass object;
```

Let's say I am running two threads A and B:

1. Thread A creates object and reads or writes some data members except a and b.
2. Thread A passes a pointer to object to a function that will run in thread B.
3. Thread B writes a or adds data to vector b.
4. Thread A reads a and b (i.e., access these for the first time).

If the answer is yes, i.e., that I need volatile in this case, I have another question: why is it thread safe to use immutable objects where data members are written in one thread and read in many others? It seems very similar to this case :)

Comment: If data members are being written to then the object is not immutable.

Comment: Also volatile is not sufficient, you need proper synchronization with something like a mutex.

Comment: thread and volatile do not have any relation, whatsoever

Comment: I do not understand item 2.  How can thread A 'pass' a pointer-to-object  to a function being run by B?  Say the function is  "void foo(MyClass& object)", what do you mean that B will run this, but A will pass the object 'to it'?

Comment: Okay, so the reason you will never have two threads writing to the same memory address is because there is the potential for a race condition where two updates could occur out of sync (or in the order you didn't expect) which can cause undefined behaviour.   Technically it is "safe" to read from mutable vars with multiple threads whilst one worker thread updates variables because there is only one thread which is mutating data, however if your updating thread is mid transaction and your reading thread does a read it will still read the old data, consider using mutexes in this case.

Comment: But to add to what everyone else has said, if the member var is immutable, it can ONLY ever be read from and never written to

Answer (score 1):

> why is it thread safe to use immutable objects where data members are written in one thread and read in many others?

Immutable objects are *created* and then never change after that point. Since multithreaded access to an object is only possible after it is created (what is there to share before then) every thread will always see the same value.

So there is never a case where an immutable object will appear differently on separate threads, since there is no way for an immutable object can change state after it has been shared.